# SSD1306 - tinydraw: screen udates are very slow

Tags: go, rp2040, tinygo

I am trying to update an image on screen based on input (button pressed)

the code look roughly like this:

```
package main

import (
  "machine"
  "time"
  "image/color"
  
  "tinygo.org/x/drivers/ssd1306"
  "tinygo.org/x/tinydraw"
)

func main() {

  UP := machine.GP17
  UP.Configure(machine.PinConfig{
    Mode: machine.PinInputPullup,
  })

  // configure the display 
  machine.I2C0.Configure(machine.I2CConfig{Frequency: machine.TWI_FREQ_400KHZ, SCL: 1, SDA: 0 })

  display := ssd1306.NewI2C(machine.I2C0)
    display.Configure(ssd1306.Config{Width: 128, Height: 64, Address: ssd1306.Address_128_32, VccState: ssd1306.SWITCHCAPVCC})

 for {
  if UP.Get(){
      display.ClearDisplay()
        tinydraw.Circle(&display, 64, 48, 8, color.RGBA{1, 1, 1, 255})
  }else{
    tinydraw.FilledCircle(&display, 64, 48, 8, color.RGBA{1, 1, 1, 255})
  }
  
    // blip on screen
    display.Display()

    // timer, without time it doens work
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 300)
  }
}
```

My question is is really why to I need the timer at the end. If I remove it, I the changes on changes are not pushed to the screen. with it, it takes too much time to update.

is there anyways to speed up the screen updating process ? maybe another lib that tinydraw?

I have tryed to change the timer, but it either takes too long to update or just stop updating whrn the value is too low.

Comment: The SSD1306 SPI interface is capable of much higher speeds than I2C.  You'll also need to look at the low-level details of your library and make sure it isn't wasting much time.